# Setting up a NordVPN gateway on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, routing, vpn, forwarding, nordvpn

**Goal**
Set up NordVPN on my Raspberry Pi and use it as a gateway.

**Current set-up**

- Raspberry Pi2 running Arch ARM, connected to my router via ethernet cable
- NordVPN account
- `nordvpn` installed on my Rpi

**Configuration**
Here is how I configured my Raspberry.
The first step is running `nordvpn` and selected the desired country. Then I have to take care of the traffic routing.

*Enabling IP forwarding:*
`echo -e 'net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf`

*Settig up NAT:*

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o nordlynx  -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i nordlynx -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o nordlynx -j ACCEPT
```

**The problem**
At this point, everything is working smoothly and I get an IP that is located in the right country. Unfortunately, most of the services like Netflix, Youtube, and some other websites, won't recognize I'm in another country.
I know it's not a NordVPN issue because the Chrome extension works properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really use `nnet.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`? It should be `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Comment: My bad, I've written on `n` more :)

Comment: Just some ideas: the website can still detect timezone, locale, cookies etc. They might be running a rather sophisticated "VPN identification" check.

Comment: It looks like you are leaking: If it were me I would run the VPN proxy as a different use. I would block direct net access for my normal users. I would add a rule to redirect normal traffic to the proxy. I would also use nftables, as they are easier.

Comment: There are online services that will check a few common leaks, like veryfing the DNS query comes from the same source. Just search for it. DNS affects answers about geolocalized services. Typical: home router provides DHCP *and* DNS. clients change their default route to the RPi, but keep using the home router for DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use a browser plugin, I just connect from the terminal. These are the steps I took to get everything running with Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit:

```
$ sudo wget -qnc https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i /pathToFile/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt install nordvpn
$ sudo usermod -aG nordvpn $USER
$ sudo nordvpn login
```

If you need local traffic, to use VNC for example, whitelist your local ip range, in my case:

```
$ nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.1.0/24
```

Not sure why, but on Linux I could not get NordVPN running without changing technologies:

```
$ nordvpn set technology nordlynx
```

Finally, we can connect!

```
$ nordvpn connect
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like being told I can only use a feature if I use only one preselected-at-setup configuration, especially when the infrastructure supports, and provides a tool for, allowing dynamic selection of the best available path at any given time on the fly.

The options I have found on the interwebs all share a common OpenVPN-only solution. Lather, rinse, repeat.

The currrent solution is as follows:

Select a single server. Download a static config file for that single server which is only available for the more inferior protocol. Walk through an unnecessarily complex setup and configuration process. Finally, keep your fingers crossed that the chosen server continues to perform consistently over time, or repeat the process again when performance degrades again, and again, and again..............
That doesn't work for me, so I went to work cracking this problem.
For those interested, I believe I have cracked the 'dynamic-nordlynx-whole-network-router' problem.

My solution:

It boils down to 4 iptables rules. Since this uses the native linux app, it can use all the features available. That means you can tell which server to connect to or let it dynamically connect to the current best one in the category you choose, such as p2p, onion, etc. Killswitch works. Autoconnect works. I think you get the idea. It would probably work using the OpenVPN protocol, but I haven't tried it because moving on from OpenVPN was part of my reason for doing this.

The iptables rules are the real key. We all know the 3 basic rules to forward traffic.

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o nordlynx -j MASQUERADE
$ iptables -A FORWARD -i <LAN> -o nordlynx -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A FORWARD -i <LAN> -o nordlynx -j ACCEPT
```

The 4th rule was a eureka moment for me after noticing the connection marking nordvpn does when it connects. This rule marks LAN connections. Without these marks iptables will drop LAN traffic due to the dynamically created nordvpn rules.

```
$ iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i <LAN> -j CONNMARK --set-mark 0xe1f1 -m comment --comment nordvpn
```

Set  to your lan facing interface.

Make sure the mark matches the firewall mark. You can find it by checking nordvpn settings

```
$ nordvpn settings
```

I have deployed this on several Proxmox VMs and lxc containers on various consumer and enterprise equipment. I'm certain this can easily be adapted to a pi. I may dig one out to try it if I find some time. My current configuration is running as an lxc on Proxmox along side a pihole lxc and pfsense vm on a N100 sff computer with 4 NICs. This setup is noticealby faster than the OpenVPN-on-pfsense combo. Although it is still in place, it's bypassed. Kept as a backup option just in case.

```
         internet
             |
           modem
             |
          Proxmox
             |<---physical port
************ | ************
*          * | *          *
*       NordVPN lxc       *
*   vmbr---->|            *
*         pfsense   vmbr  *
*          * | * \<----   *
*          * | *  pihole  *
************ | ************
   |         |        |<---physical ports
  LAN      WiFi     Guest
```

I tried to post his on the nordvpn subreddit, but apparently I don't have enough karma.

I just want to help others when I can.

My project and fairly complete writeup for my linux-based router can be found here:
https://github.com/theOtherLuke/nordlynx-router/tree/main